# use diese as a character, not like comment in a yml file

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I try to declare a route to use angular,in my security.yml after authentication i well be redirect to #/welcome but consider it a comment

```
default_target_path: #/welcome
```

my app.js

```
routeApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) { 
// Routing system
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: Routing.generate('login'),
        controller: 'SecurityController'
    })
    .when('/welcome', {
        templateUrl: Routing.generate('ard_backend_test'),
        controller: 'WelcomeController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a double quote for your string and the hash # character will be able to escape.

```
default_target_path: "#/welcome"
```

**Update:** Do not define the default client route in your yml configuration.
This should be part of your angular router configuration. Depending which router you are using of course.

Here is an example with angular's [default routeService](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07):

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])
       .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/welcome', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/welcome.tpl.html',
        controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'
      }).
      when('/some-other-route', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/some-other-route.tpl.html',
        controller: 'SomeOtherCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/welcome'
      });
  }]);
```

Comment: this is the error i take when i'm adding double quote : Unable to generate a URL for the named route "#/welcome" as such route does not exist.

Comment: @Mahmoud let angular router decide the default "client" url not your server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, actually that's what I did, but in the security.yml file I have to define the patern after authentication

Comment: Just try to use the plain forward slash in your yml '/'

Comment: in fact I used to disconnect I put '/' that redirects me to the login page, that's why I have to spend another pattern because I have to be redirected to another road ;)